# Multiple threads to data to array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, c++11

I'm using for loop to create given number of threads, each one of them makes approximation of part of my integral, I want them to give that data back to array so later I can sum it up (if I think right, I can't just make sum += in each thread because they will collide), everything worked right, to the moment when I want to take that data from each thread, I get error:

```
calka.cpp:49:33: error: request for member 'get_future' in 'X', which is of non-class type 'std::promise<float>[(N + -1)]'
```

code:

```
#include <iostream> //cout  
#include <thread> //thread
#include <future> //future , promise
#include <stdlib.h> //atof
#include <string> //string
#include <sstream> //stringstream

using namespace std;

// funkcja 4x^3 + (x^2)/3 - x + 3
// całka x^4 + (x^3)/9 - (x^2)/2 + 3x 

void thd(float begin, float width, promise<float> & giveback)
{   
    float x = begin + 1/2 * width;
    float height = x*x*x*x + (x*x*x)/9 - (x*x)/2 + 3*x ; 
    float outcome = height * width;
    giveback.set_value(outcome);    

    stringstream ss;
    ss << this_thread::get_id();
    string output = "thread #id: " + ss.str() + "  outcome" + to_string(outcome);

    cout << output << endl;
    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    int sum = 0;
    float begin = atof(argv[1]);
    float size = atof(argv[2]);
    int N = atoi(argv[3]);
    float end = begin + N*size;

    promise<float> X[N-1];



    thread t[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        t[i] = thread(&thd, begin, size, ref(X[i]));
        begin += size;
    }

    future<float> wynik_ftr = X.get_future();
    float wyniki[N-1];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        t[i].join();
        wyniki[i] = wynik_ftr.get();
    }
    //place for loop adding outcome from threads to sum
    cout << N;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you mean to use X[0].get_future() instead of X.get_future();

Comment: Simpler solution is to use `std::async` instead of `std::thread` combined with `std::promise.`

Comment: you are right, code runs, why 0 there and not [N-1]? Also it causes ```Segmentation fault (core dumped)``` error, sometimes with printing threads cout sometimes without

Comment: Undefined behavior. The shown code runs off the end of the array, corrupting memory, and resulting in an almost guaranteed crash.

Comment: @Jasude `promise<float> X[N-1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime variable.  Why aren't you using `std::vector` here?  You're using other "advanced" parts of C++.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use VLA - `promise<float> X[N-1]`. It is an extension of some compilers, so your code is not portable. Use `std::vector` instead.

It seems you want to split calculation of integral to `N` threads. You create `N-1` background threads and one invocation of `thd` is executed from `main` thread. In `main` you join all results, so 
you don't need to create `wyniki` as array to store a result per thread, 
because you are gathering these results in serially manner - inside for loop in `main` function. 
Therefore one `float wyniki` variable is sufficient.

Steps you have to do are:

- prepare `N` promises
- starts `N-1` threads
- call `thd` from main
- join and add results from `N-1` threads in for loop
- join and add main thread result

Code:

```
std::vector<promise<float>> partialResults(N);

std::vector<thread> t(N-1);

for (int i = 0; i<N-1; i++) {
    t[i] = thread(&thd, begin, size, ref(partialResults[i]));
    begin += size;
}

thd(begin,size,ref(partialResults[N-1]));
float wyniki = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i<N-1; i++) {
    t[i].join();
    std::future<float> res = partialResults[i].get_future();
    wyniki  += res.get();
}
std::future<float> res = partialResults[N-1].get_future(); // get res from main
wyniki += res.get();

cout << wyniki << endl;
```